# Determine Original Object Type after Casting to Interface Type

Tags: java, interface, casting

I have an object which implements an interface. The object is created, but is assigned the data type of the interface, similar to:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In this example, `ArrayList` is implicitly cast into a `List` type. How would I programmically later on determine that `List someList` is in fact, an `ArrayList` in disguise?

Must I use `instanceof` with a bunch of selection statements to determine the true type? Or is there a way to get the class name of the original type?

Hopefully this is a good example, the actual code is more complex and deals with custom data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can get the `Class` type of the actual object, using [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method.

```
class Parent { }
class Child extends Parent { }

class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        System.out.println(parent.getClass());  // Child.class
    }
}
```

Comment: even though it's been cast to another type?

Comment: @SnakeDoc What do you mean by cast to another type? The assignment that you've done in your question, doesn't have any cast. It just has widening conversion.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It has not been cast to another type, strictly speaking. The object reference has just changed, and allows you access to certain methods inside the original object. The object itself is still very much a `Child` object.

Comment: good example. surprised how simple this is... i was way over-thinking this. i'll accept when timer runs out.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I think more issues are caused by overthinking than underthinking.